# Prevent chrome to have only one root process

Tags: google-chrome, process, chromium

When I launch a chrome process, if there is no chrome process already present, every argument I pass to the process is preserved (e.g. `chrome --my-custom-process-id=guid`). But after the second launch chromes kills the new process instantly and creates a new child process of the first one (the root chrome process), removing my custom arg.

How can I have multiple root chrome processes where it preserves its passed arguments? Is it possible with current chrome multi-process architecture?

[image: Root Process]